# .Net Couchbase XATTR example from docs not compiling

Tags: .net, couchbase

We are evaluating if we should use [extended attributes](https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/2.7/sdk-xattr-overview.html) to store an 'app licence expiry' data along with each CB server User.

The [example](https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/2.7/sdk-xattr-example.html) was copied/pasted into a .net framework console app.

A few examples:

```
bucket.MutateIn<dynamic>("hotel_10138")
                    .Upsert("discounts.jsmith123", "20", SubdocMutateFlags.CreatePath | SubdocMutateFlags.XattrPath)
```

and

```
cluster.CreateManager().UpsertUser("jsmith123", "jsmith123pwd", "John Smith",
                    new Role[]
                    { ... });
```

However the code is  throwing a few compile errors:

1 - Any of the dozen or so refs to 'SubdocMutateFlags' gives the following: 
**The name 'SubdocMutateFlags' does not exist in the current context**

2 - On the line **cluster.CreateManager().UpsertUser("jsmith123", ...** we get the following error: **cannot convert from 'string' to 'Couchbase.Management.AuthenticationDomain'**

Nuget packeage installed: CouchbaseNetClient.

All the usings are in place, any idea whys this isn't working?

Comment: Would you mind posting the smallest possible snippet of code so that I can try reproducing this issue?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I just copied and pasted the example linked above directly into a console app and imported Nuget package CouchbaseNetClient.

Answer (score 1):

This sample definitely needs to be updated.

First, instead of `SubdocMutateFlags`, use `SubdocPathFlags`. Instead of `SubdocPathFlags.XattrPath`, use `SubdocPathFlags.Xattr`.

Next, for `UpsertUser`, you will need to specify an Authentication Domain as a parameter. So, something like this:

```
cluster.CreateManager().UpsertUser(AuthenticationDomain.Local, "jsmith123", "jsmith123pwd", "John Smith",
                    new Role[]
                    { ... } );
```

With those changes, it should at least compile. However, even with those changes in place, I'm still getting a runtime exception now of `ObjectDisposedException` (so I've created a ticket [DOC-6347](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-6347) for this code sample to be reviewed and updated). Also, this sample will query and loop through the *entire* bucket, using the primary key. So definitely keep in mind that is definitely not something you should do in production code.

Finally, I'd encourage you to reach out to the [Couchbase Forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/net-sdk) (or Couchbase Support if you are an Enterprise customer) to check and see if using XATTR is the right tool for the job. Generally speaking, XATTR usage is discouraged except for narrow, framework-like situations.

Comment: Ok thank you I will give your suggestions a try. The purpose was to store an expiry date in a user object but I dont think this is possible. Are you aware of any way to add key/values to the user object (ie the same user that we create with the admin api that includes un/pw, channels etc..) so that I don't need to hit another api.

Comment: You must have asked a similar question in the forums: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/add-additional-user-key-values/24953

Comment: Yes Matthew I asked on here first then took your advice and reached out to the couchbase forum.